# Cases re-assigned to queue after agent claims from Omni Channel and saves case

Tags: case, queue, omnichannel

I set up Omni Channel in an org, and my users have been working with it for a couple of weeks. Major issue - every time an agent accepts a case, and save it, it gets reassigned back to the queue. Is this supposed to happen with Omni Channel?

Especially interesting is that in the feed it says that 'System' changed the owner back to the queue. If it was a hidden flow or process builder or trigger code that was causing this I'd expect the User that was active to be the one who changed the owner.

I've disabled all Case Assignment rules, so it shouldn't be that.

Any help would be appreciated, my client is talking about turning off Omni-Channel and manually assigning cases!

Comment: I assume you have the field history for owner enabled, does that history again shows 'System'?

Comment: Following is a standard behavior with Omni-channel -->

> If your agent is available and a case is proposed to them (even if they don't accept the case) in the background the case gets assigned to them and then it gets assigned back to the queue. In the case history this will show as two changes of ownership (which can be quite confusing since nothing really happened) 

Ref : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000319828&type=1

But seems like, your agents are accepting the cases. I suspect some automation is triggering the change. Please check process builders, flows and apex

Comment: It looks like you are right - it was being assigned in the 'background', not accepted properly. We're pushing the process with our agents now. If you put this as the answer I'll accept it. @prabuddhkumar

Comment: thank you, I have posted it as an answer. Glad I could help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a standard behavior with Omni-channel --> > If your agent is available and a case is proposed to them (even if they don't accept the case) in the background the case gets assigned to them and then it gets assigned back to the queue. In the case history this will show as two changes of ownership (which can be quite confusing since nothing really happened)

Ref : help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000319828&type=1

But seems like, your agents are accepting the cases. I suspect some automation is triggering the change. Please check process builders, flows and apex

Answer (score 0):

We had exactly this issue on our Org and it pointed out that a BatchJob was triggering the Case Assignment Rules on Upsert which leads to the problem that the owner of the case was changed back to the queue. I recommend to search your codebase for something like this:

```
AssignmentRule currentAssignmentRule = [
   SELECT Id
   FROM AssignmentRule
   WHERE SobjectType = 'Case' AND Active = TRUE
];

Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmlOpts.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId = currentAssignmentRule.Id;

caseSobject.setOptions(this.dmlOpts);
```

Applying the dml options for new cases exclusively fixed the problem for us